# Logging into a website from a Windows Desktop Gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm developing a Windows Desktop Gadget. From within the gadget, I have to login to an external website, get a response from a specific page and display required information from it.

I have implemented the request using jQuery's `$.post()`. First, I send the post parameters to the application and it receives a 302 response.  After that, when I send subsequent jQuery `$.get()` requests to other pages, it is not posting the required cookies.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tute on using cookies with windows gadgets..

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2006/09/28/making-rest-calls-and-using-session-state-from-a-sidebar-gadget_2e00_*2e00*_2e00_.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2006/09/28/making-rest-calls-and-using-session-state-from-a-sidebar-gadget_2e00__2e00__2e00_.aspx)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2006/09/28/making-rest-calls-and-using-session-state-from-a-sidebar-gadget_2e00__2e00__2e00_.aspx

Comment: @Neeraj editing your post would've been a better response. :)

Comment: @eml :Much faster this way... ;)

Comment: @elm: finally gave in to your arguments... :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Desktop Gadgets don't automatically store cookies from XMLHttpRequests.  You should be able to use `getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` and then set them for future requests by specifying them in the `headers` config for `$.ajax`.

For more information, see the [HTTP cookie (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).